# MySQL Post-Installation on a Mac OSX Snow Leopard

Tags: mysql, setup, osx-snow-leopard

I installed MySQL on a Mac OSX Snow Leopard and got the mysql service started but I couldn't login as root to reset the password.

2. Couldn't login as root either.

   $ ./mysql -u root
   ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
3. Neither did mysqladmin work

   ./mysqladmin -u root password "password"
   ./mysqladmin: connect to server at 'localhost' failed
   error: 'Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)'

How do set/reset my MySQL password ?

Comment: Try a blank password like - `mysql -u root -p` [mysql password option](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-command-options.html#option_mysql_password)

Comment: Tried that - doesnt log in.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are first logged into your local system as root, and then reset the password with mysqladmin like:

```
./mysqladmin -u root password "password"
```